# Distributive law for $\mathbb{C}$-Modules monad and $\mathbb{N}$-Modules monad

Tags: category-theory, modules, monads

I recently [asked a question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332874/quantum-scattering-experiments-c-modules-n-modules-and-their-monads)  and it contains a reference to the monads  $\mathcal{M}_N$ and $ \mathcal{M}_C$, which are the multiset and  $\mathcal{C}$-module monad, respectively.  I want to define a distributive law for the composition   $\mathcal{M}_C \cdot \mathcal{M}_N$.  I am guessing there is a large freedom to define the distributive law and I won't know how to choose one.  Basically, I want a monad that is a complex combination (c-module) of numbers of things of  different types (multiset).   I am asking for any help, hints,  or complete solutions.

A distributive law is necessary to be able to compose the functors of two monads and generate a new monad from the composition. That is what I am looking for, the monad derived fromt the composition.  At the same time, it would be nice to know the modules that result from the composition of $ \mathbb{N}$-modules and $ \mathbb{C}$-modules.  I think that composition is a tensor product.  These would be complex combinations of multisets.

Comment: I'm not sure you're indeed looking for a distributive law. Don't you simply want to generate instead the free $\Bbb C$-vector space over your possible multisets? Anyway, it's not clear, what structure(s) are you considering on $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb N$. The term 'distributive law' is originated from the case of mere monoids $(\Bbb N,+)$ and $(\Bbb N,\cdot)$, and is basically the generalization of the connection $a\cdot (b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$ for monads.